# Fluid images in table

Tags: html, css, xhtml, responsive-design, fluid-images

First of all, i only wrote some of this code. It's a single html file, that will be mailed to people as a newsletter. Im using tables here, cause as far as i know, it's the best option we got so far? Well, that problem is my images. I usually use img{max-width: 100%;}, so the images never override the edges of my document, but scales down automatically. I can't get this to work when i use tables. Sorry for the VERY messy code, again, i didnt write it :)

There is also a link to a preview [here](http://thomasteilmann.com/nyhedsbrev/juni_test.html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0"/>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"  />
    <title>ezzence.dk</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        table{
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        .clearfix:before,
        .clearfix:after {
            content: " "; /* 1 */
            display: table; /* 2 */
        }

        .clearfix:after {
            clear: both;
        }

        /*
         * For IE 6/7 only
         * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
         */

    .clearfix {
        *zoom: 1;
    }

    body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background-color: #fff;
       width: 100%;
            font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
    }

    td.permission {
       padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    }

    .permission p{

       font-weight: normal;
       color: #151515;
       font-size: .8em;
    }

    .permission p a {

       font-weight: normal;
       color: #a72323;
    }

     td.header1 {
          background-color: #fff;
     }

    td.header1 a img {
         border: none;
     }

     td.header2 a img {
          border:none;
     }

    table.content {
       background-color: #fff;
    }

    td.sidebar a {

       font-size: 11px;
       font-weight: normal;
       color: #000;
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    td.sidebar ul {
       margin: 0 0 0 24px;
       padding: 0;
    }

    td.sidebar ul li,
    td.sidebar ul li a {

       font-size: 12px;
       font-weight: normal;
       color: #a72323;
    }

    td.sidebar h3 {

       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #333333;
       margin: 10px 0 14px 0;
       padding: 0;
    }


    p {

       font-weight: normal;
       color: #505050;
       margin: 0 0 13px 0;
       padding: 0;
    }

    td.sidebar p.buttons {

       font-size: 11px;
       font-weight: normal;
       color: #505050;
       margin: 0 0 4px 0;
       padding: 0;
    }

    td.border {
       border-right: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    }

    td.mainbar a {
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #000;
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    td.mainbar h2 {
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: 800;
       color: #000;
       margin: 0 0 4px 0;
       padding: 0 0 4px 10px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    }

    td.mainbar h3 {

       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: normal;
       color: #000;
       margin: 10px 0 16px 30px;
       padding: 0;
    }

     td.mainbar h5 {

       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: normal;
         text-decoration:underline;
       color: #000;
       margin: 10px 0 16px 30px;
       padding: 0;
    }

    td.mainbar p {

       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: normal;
       color: #000;
       margin: 5px 30px 16px 30px;
       padding: 0;
    }

    td.mainbar p.top {

       font-size: 10px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #a72323;
       margin: 0 0 30px 0;
       padding: 0;
    }

    td.mainbar p.top a {
       font-size: 10px;
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #f5f5f5;
    }

    td.mainbar ul {
       font-size: 14px;
       font-weight: normal;
       color: #ffffff;
       margin: 5px 30px 16px 50px;
       padding: 0;
    }

     td.footer {
       padding:10 70 10 70; 
       text-align:center;
             padding-top: 13px ;
            line-height: 1.8;
    }

    td.footer p {
       font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
       font-weight: normal;
       color: #151515;
       font-size: .8em;    
    }
    a{
        outline:none;
        }
    a image { border:0; }

        a{
            outline:none;
             text-decoration: none;
             color: #fff;  
         }
        a image { border:0; }

         #wrapper{
            width: 960px;
            max-width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
         }

         #info{
             font-size: 12px;
             font-weight: normal;
             color: #151515;
             margin: 0 auto;
             text-align: center;
             margin-bottom: 20px;
         }

         img{
            max-width: 100%;
         }

         #navigation{
            text-align:center;
         }

         #navigation ul li{
            list-style-type: none; 
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: .85em;
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 8%;
         }

         ul li a:hover{
            color: #656565;
         }

         #maintext{
            color: #222222;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            font-size: .8em; 
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 1.5;
         }

         #maintext h3{
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: bold;
         }


         #bottom_menu{
            height: 30px;
        }

         #social_media{
            float: left;
         }

         #social_media a{

         }

         #ezzence_desc h5{
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
            padding: 0;
         }

         #ezzence_desc{
            font-size: .8em;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            line-height: 1.5;
         }

         #bottom_text{
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #151515;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
         }

         .social_button{
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
         }

        .centerimage{
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #products{
            width: 100%;
        }

        #products a{

        }

        .last_element{
            padding: 0 !important;
        }

        #products a{
            float: left;
            max-width: 50%;
        }

        .productimganchor{
            float: left;   
        }

        .left{
            float: left;
        }

        .right{
            float: right;
        }

        .bottom_menu_item{
            padding-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .bottom_menu_item a{
            font-size: .9em;
            -webkit-transition-property: color;
            -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
        }

        .bottom_menu_item a:hover{
            color: #bcbcbc;
        }

        .menu_item{
            padding:0px 55px 0px 0px;
        }

        .menu_item a, .last_element a{
            color: #313131;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: bold;

            -webkit-transition-property: color;
            -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
        }

        .menu_item a:hover, .last_element a:hover{
            color: #6f6f6f;
        }

         /* Mobile (portrait and landscape) */
        @media screen 
            and (min-device-width : 320px) 
            and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        }

        /* Mobile (landscape) */
        @media screen and (min-width : 321px) {

        }

        /* Mobile (portrait) */
        @media screen and (max-width : 320px), (max-device-width : 320px) {
            .permission p{
                color: red;
                font-size: .8em !important;
            }
            img{
                max-width: 100% !important;
            }

            .menu_item{
                width: %;
            }

            .last_element{
                width: 100%;
            }

            .products_div img{

            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width : 768px), (max-device-width : 768px){
            p, p a{
            font-size: 14pt !important;
            }

            .bottom_menu_item a{
                font-size: 1.1em;
            }   

            h4{
                font-size: 1.8em;
            }

            #bottom_menu{
                height: 50px;
            }

            .menu_item a, .last_element a{
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width : 763px), (max-device-width : 763px){
        }

        @media screen and (max-width : 850px), (max-device-width : 850px){

        }

        @media screen and (max-width : 645px), (max-device-width : 645px){


        }

        /* Tablet (portrait and landscape) */
        @media screen
            and (min-device-width : 768px) 
            and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

        }

        /* Tablet (landscape) */
        @media screen 
            and (min-device-width : 768px) 
            and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
            and (orientation : landscape) {
        }

        /* Tablet (portrait) */
        @media screen 
            and (min-device-width : 768px)
            and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
            and (orientation : portrait) {
            p{
                font-size: 14px ;
            }
        }

        /* Desktop */
        @media only screen and (min-width:1025px){

        }

        /* High-Res */
        @media  
            screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),
            screen and (-moz-min.device-pixel-ratio:2),
            screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2) {

        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
            /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
        }

        @media print,
               (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
               (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
               (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
            /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
        }


     </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="wrapper" width="960" style="max-width: 90% !important; margin: 0 auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td class="permission" align="center"><p> Årets støreste kampagne er i gang. Få tip til den perfekte øjenskygge til din øjenfarve.<br />
                      Fri fragt når du handler for 500 kr. Leveres indenfor 1-3 dage.<br />
                  Kan du ikke læse nyhedsbrevet? <webversion>Klik her</webversion></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border: 1px solid red;">
                    <td style="" class="header1" align="left" valign="bottom" ><a href="http://ezzence.dk" ><img src="img/header.jpg" border="0" alt="Ezzence Nyhedsbrev" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:#fff; font-size:12px;" width="100%">
                        <table align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td class="menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/haar-pleje.html">H&aring;rpleje</a></td>
                                <td class="menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/hudpleje.html">Hudpleje</a></td>
                                <td class="menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/krop-og-velvaere.html">Krop og Velv&aelig;re</a></td>
                                <td class="menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/makeup.html">Make up</a></td>
                                <td class="menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/gaveideer.html">Gaveid&eacute;er</a></td>
                                <td class="last_element"><a href="http://ezzence-magazine.dk">Magazine</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://ezzence.dk/weekendsale" target="_blank"><img src="img/nyhedsbanner.jpg" alt="ezzence kampagne" style="margin:10px 0;" border="0"/></a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" >
                            <tr>  
                                <!-- Tekstindhold --> 
                                <td class="mainbar" align="left" valign="top" width="500"  style="margin-top:20px;" >

                                    <br /><br />
                                  <h3 style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#222222;" >Matcher din øjenskygge din øjenfarve?</h3>
                                  <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;">Vidste du, at farven på din øjenskygge har stor betydning for intensiteten af dine øjne?</p>
                                  <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;">Uanset om du har blå, grønne eller måske brune øjne, så kan den rigtige farve øjenskygge gøre underværker for intensiteten af dine øjne.</p>
                                  <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;"><strong>Grønne øjne:</strong> hvis du vælger en farve med rød-lilla pigmenter fremhæves det grønne i dine øjne.</p>
                                   <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;"><strong>Blå øjne:</strong> vælg farver med orange, gyldne eller bronze pigmenter, der komplimenterer den blå farver og får den til at virke skarpere og mere intens.</p>
                                  <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;"><strong>Brune øjne:</strong> brune øjne er fantastiske. Hvis bare du holder dig fra en brun øjenskygge, der har nøjagtig samme farve som dine øjne, så kan du ikke gå galt i byen.</p>
                                  <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;">Tag et kig på vores mange fine øjenskygger på ezzence.dk eller find makeup fra: <a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/janeiredal.html" target="_blank">Jane Iredale</a>, <a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/youngblood.html" target="_blank">Youngblood</a>, <a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/smashbox.html" target="_blank">Smashbox</a> og mangel flere. </p>
                                  <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;">De bedste hilsner<br />
                                  Sofie – <a href="http://ezzence.dk" target="_blank">ezzence.dk</a></p>
                                   <p style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight:regular; color:#222222;"><strong>Psst..</strong>Husk at vi stadig har 20-60 % på mere end 3000 skønhedsprodukter, find hele kampagnen lige <a href="http://ezzence.dk/weekendsale" target="_blank">her</a>.</p>

                                  <!--      @page { margin: 2cm }       P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm }     -->

                              </td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>


      <br />
      <a href="http://ezzence.agillic.eu/pclk/Q7PVJ/Week26sunday/0?ct_id=[EMAIL]">

<img alt=""src="img/ole_henriksen.jpg"/>

</a>


<a href="http://ezzence.agillic.eu/pclk/Q7PVJ/Week26sunday/1?ct_id=[EMAIL]">

<img alt="" src="img/clean.jpg"/>

</a>

            <div class="products_div">

            <div style="float:left; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/clean.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/clean_2.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

             <div style="float:right;border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/janeiredal.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/jane.jpg" alt="Billede" /></a></div>

            </div>                           
                     <div class="products_div">

            <div style="float:left; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/john-masters-organics.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/john.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

             <div style="float:right; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/joico.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/joico.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

            </div>  



            <div class="products_div">

                <div style="float:left; width:355 px;  border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/kevin-murphy.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/kevin.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

                 <div style="float:right; width:355 px;  border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/opi.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/opi.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

            </div>  



            <div class="products_div">

                <div style="float:left;border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/ole-henriksen.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/ole.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

                 <div style="float:right; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/nuxe.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/nuxe.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

            </div>  


            <div class="products_div" >

                <div style="float:left; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/paul-mitchell.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/paul.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

                 <div style="float:right; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/youngblood.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/yb.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

            </div>  


           <div class="products_div" >

                <div style="float:left; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/tigi.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/tigi.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

                 <div style="float:right; border: 1px #e3e3e3 solid ;"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/maerker/clinique.html" target="_blank"><img src="img/clinique.jpg" alt="Billede"/></a></div>

            </div>  
<br/><br/>

                      <table align="center" style="position:relative; margin-top:20px; margin: 0 auto; ">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="">


                                </td>
                                <td align="center" style="width: 100%; padding-top: 25px;">
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ezzence.dk" target="_blank"><img src="img/se-flere.jpg" alt="seflere"/></a>
                                    <br/><br/>
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ezzence.dk" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.jpg" alt="facebook"/></a>
                                    <br/><br/>
                                    <a href="http://www.ezzence-magazine.dk/" target="_blank"><img src="img/blog.jpg" alt="magazine"/></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                      </table>

                        <table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000" style="width: 100%; ">
                            <tr id="bottom_menu" style="background-color: black; text-align: center; ">
                                <td class="bottom_menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk"  target="_blank">ezzence.dk</a></td>
                                <td class="bottom_menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/kundeservice"  target="_blank">Kundeservice</a></td>
                                <td class="bottom_menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/handelsbetingelser" target="_blank">Handelsbetingelser</a></td>
                                <td class="bottom_menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/handelsbetingelser" target="_blank">Levering &amp; Returnering</a></td>
                                <td class="bottom_menu_item"><a href="http://ezzence.dk/contacts/" target="_blank">Kontakt os</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 20px; padding-top: 15px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="32px" style="float: left; padding:0px 0px 0px 4px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ezzence.dk" target="_blank"><img src="http://ezzence.dk/media/images/nyhedsbrev/2012/ikoner/facebookicon.jpg" height="32" width="32"border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a></td>
                                <td width="32px" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" ><a href="http://www.youtube.com/ezzenceDK" target="_blank"> <img src="http://ezzence.dk/media/images/nyhedsbrev/2012/ikoner/youtubeicon.jpg" height="32" width="32"border="0" alt="Youtube" /></a></td>
                                <td width="32px" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" ><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/ezzence_dk/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ezzence.dk/media/images/nyhedsbrev/2012/ikoner/twittericon.jpg" height="32" width="32"border="0" alt="Twitter" /></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                
                        <table align="center" style="margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 8px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="http://www.trustpilot.dk/review/www.ezzence.dk" target="_blank"><img src="img/trustpilot.jpg"  border="0"  alt="Trustpilot"/></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                   </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="footer" style="padding: 20px;">
                        <h4>Eksklusive og økologiske skønhedsprodukter</h4>
                        <p>Formålet med ezzence.dk er at gøre eksklusive skønhedsprodukter tilgængelige for den kvalitetsbevidste forbruger. Tilgængelige i den forstand, at du som forbruger vil kunne finde et stort udvalg af mange af de mest innovative og lækre luksusmærker på ezzence.dk - lige fra mærker med gennembrydende teknologi til økologiske skønhedsprodukter.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="footer" style="border-top: 1px dashed #898989; padding: 20px;">
                        <p>Kampagnen er gældende fra d.27.06. til d.02.07.<br/>
                         Priserne er beregnet ud fra vejledende udsalgsspris. Vi tager forbehold for udsolgte varer, prisfejl og trykfejl.
                         <br/>Ønsker du ikke længere at modtage nyhedsbrevet? - <unsubscribe>Klik her</unsubscribe></p>
                      <a href="http://ezzence.dk" target="_blank"><img src="img/ezzence.jpg"  border="0"  alt="ezzence"/></a></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>                                              
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, you need to paste relevant code here, and it will be better if you try to provide a fiddle

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann in your preview, what went wrong? Point out the area.

Comment: Usually people wants to see the whole code, but i'm gonna sort something out in second. I have never tried fiddle, but im gonna take a look at it

Comment: There is a bunch of divs with a class="product_div". The images inside wont resize with max-width: 100%;.. I can see now that they are not inside a table, but that just makes it weirder

Comment: Isn't the problem simply that the table cannot get narrower than about 665 pixels, so even if the window is narrower that that, the document won't shrink any further?

Comment: When processing email I throw away HTML head and body elements and use what is inside the body element only. I also suck out the style and apply it. You haven't mentioned what browser/versions you're working to make this happen in. I'd recommend not messing with anything below IE8 at this time.